# How to create ImageView from another class

Tags: java, android-studio, nullpointerexception, imageview

I want to create ImageVIew from my class but i've got some exeptions and dont know why. Please help me.
Here is my  class

public class Card  {

```
Bitmap bitmap;

 public Card( Bitmap bitmap, LinearLayout linearLayout,Context context){
    ImageView imageView=new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
             ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     linearLayout.addView(imageView);
}
```

and

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.jpg);
Card card;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout linearLayout=findViewById(R.id.ll);
    card=new Card(bitmap,linearLayout,this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: please give us the exception stracktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.jpg);
```

definition in the onCreate method. And this should solve the NullPointerException because the context is not defined yet.

So it should look as follow:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Bitmap bitmap;
Card card;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.jpg);
    LinearLayout linearLayout=findViewById(R.id.ll);
    card=new Card(bitmap,linearLayout,this);
    ....
```